# Accessing MIT/GNU Scheme's REPL return value

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop, mit-scheme

Is there a symbol that is used to refer to the return value of the last evaluated expression in the MIT/GNU Scheme repl?

For example:

Python uses `_`

Haskell uses `it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Common Lisp which has the `*` REPL variable for this purpose, Scheme leaves this feature to implementors.

In MIT Scheme this can only be done in the builtin Edwin editor (accessed with `mit-scheme --edit` or by calling the `(edit)` function from the command line REPL). After executing something in the REPL, you can see the last result by entering `C-x C-e`. If you are not familiar with Emacs style commands, more information can be found at http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.034s/04/scheme.html in the Key Bindings section.